# How to push in ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to push `state_id` and save state_name in database.

Look at my codes.

httml

```
<select id="state_id" name="state_id">

</select>

<select id="city_id" name="city_id">

</select>
```

js

```
function saveAddress() {
    var url = "ShoppingController/store";
    var data = $('#addAddress').serializeArray();
    var state_name = $('#state_id option:selected').text();
    var city_name = $('#city_id option:selected').text();
    data.push({'name':'state_name', 'value':state_name});
    data.push({'name':'city_name', 'value':city_name});
    $.post(url, data, function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });
}
```

ShoppingController.php

```
function save($data)
{
    Model::session_start();
    $user_id = Model::session_get('user_id');
    $first_last_name = $data['first_last_name'];
    $mobile = $data['mobile'];
    $telephone = $data['telephone'];
    $state_id = $data['state_id'];
    $state_name = $data['state_name'];
    $city_id = $data['city_id'];
    $city_name = $data['city_name'];
    $address = $data['address'];
    $postal_code = $data['postal_code'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_address (user_id, first_last_name, mobile, telephone, state_id, city_id, address, postal_code, state_name, city_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $params = [$user_id, $first_last_name, $mobile, $telephone, $state_id, $city_id, $address, $postal_code, $state_name, $city_name];
    $this->doQuery($sql, $params);
}
```

I see this error.

> Notice: Undefined index: state_name in C:\xampp3\htdocs\projects\digikala\php\models\Shopping.php on line 18 Notice: Undefined index: city_name in C:\xampp3\htdocs\projects\digikala\php\models\Shopping.php on line 20

Comment: You don't have an error for `first_last_name` ?

Comment: It's helpful if instead of posting extracts of code you provide the whole thing. If this is indeed all the code there's then you're missing A LOT of suff, i also want to point out that this approach is both confussing and insecure, it uses aspects of both procedural and oop programming, use the oop approach and i suggest you use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to deal with DB I/O.

Comment: @Minnen is right. Please provide more context. Start by showing us `#addAddress` and also please post the result of `console.log(data);` before you do the XHR call. Have you checked your developer tools' console for errors?

Comment: Either the indexes with errors have no data attached to them or your table indexes don't exist.